# Function of jxl.jar in java

Tags: java, jar

Hi all 
What is the main function of jxl.jar in java...does JExcelApi has any connection with jxl.java Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jxl.jar` is the library of [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)  , which is a open source java API  to read, write, and modify Excel spreadsheets dynamically.  It contains all the compiled *.class files, associated metadata and resources that are used by the Java Excel API internally .

Java library are  distributed  as a .jar file .You can refer to [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for more info about JAR.

As the [official API of JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/) does not contain a file called `jxl.java` .I believe this is the Java class created by you to test the function of JExcelApi  . To use the JExcelApi  , you have to import the necessary classes from the `jxl.jar` and specified `jxl.jar` to be on the class path when you compile `jxl.java` .

So , the connection between `jxl.java` and `jxl.jar` is that `jxl.java` calls the classes from `jxl.jar` to manipulate the Excel.